# Does the Fade Away gnome racial feat require concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, concentration, gnomes

Does the invisibility that the Fade Away racial feat (for gnomes) grants require concentration or would using it drop any spells the user is currently concentrating on?

The wording doesn't specifically say that (you *become* invisible, you don't *cast* the *invisibility* spell). I am unsure of how it works, and can't find the answer online. How does Fade Away work?

Comment: I removed the bit about taking suggestions for Feat choices as that's more of a discussion and idea generation which we don't really do here. Please take our [tour] to learn more about the stack, and once you've got enough rep (20), you can hop into [chat] for more opinion-based idea generation stuff :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### It does not require Concentration

The [Fade Away](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/fade-away) feat (XGtE, p. 74) says:

> Immediately after you take damage, you can use a reaction to magically become invisible until the end of your next turn or until you attack, deal damage, or force someone to make a saving throw. Once you use this ability, you can’t do so again until you finish a short or long rest.

If the feature required concentration, it would say so. Similarly, if it was casting the spell *invisibility*, it would say so. However, it says neither of those things. As you intuit, you do not need to use concentration for the feat.